# NASA Astronaut Group 2 Press Conference

Tags: nasa, astronauts, reference-request

Is there footage of the [NASA Astronaut Group 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Astronaut_Group_2) press conference online? I can watch the press conference for the Mercury astronauts [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXj5lc_QUOM), but can't find [Group 2](http://www.spacefacts.de/groups/photo2/nasa-2.jpg) footage. I've seen snippets of the 1962 Group 2 press conference in Nasa documentaries, so I know it exists somewhere.